# Get data from second table with Laravel Eloquent relationship

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I have tables `users` and `gender`

In gender table there is `id` and `name` (male/female)

And in `users` table there is `gender_id`

I need to get json with data from users table and gender name from gender table based on connected id. With current code I'm getting correct `gender_id` but also `gender: null` for all users. How can I show name from gender table in json?

This is what I have:

**User model**

```
public function Gender()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Gender', 'id');
}
```

**Gender model**

```
public function User()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\User', 'gender_id');
}
```

**Controller**

```
$users = User::with('Gender')->paginate(5);
return response()->json($users);
```

**json response**

```
{
    "total": 10,
    "per_page": 5,
    "current_page": 1,
    "last_page": 2,
    "next_page_url": "http://test.com/user?page=2",
    "prev_page_url": null,
    "from": 1,
    "to": 5,
    "data": [
        {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "John",
        "surname": "Doe",
        "gender_id": 1,
        "tel": "987654321",
        "email": "john.doe@email.com",
        "gender": null
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I think your relation should be `User belongsTo Gender` instead of `hasOne`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, a user has one gender. That so, you set a `gender_id` for later the model to be called. And to get the gender, you're likely going to *transform* the id of gender on user table, `gender_id`, to a real model. So, `belongsTo` should be correct.

**User model**

```
public function Gender()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Gender', 'gender_id', 'id);
}
```

The owning side, with my logical thinking, a gender can be owned by many users, or it can has many users or else similar phrase.

**Gender model**

```
public function Users()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\User', 'gender_id', 'id);
}
```

I put extra `s` to the method for better naming convention.

Comment: I have additional question. Is it possible to declare columns in model that I want to get? For example if gender table has column `status` beside `id` and `name` and I want to exclude that status from result.

Comment: Something like this https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-serialization#hiding-attributes-from-json ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for [model mutators](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-mutators)

In your case i should go for an [accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators)

For example:

```
public function getGenderNameAttribute()
{
    return ($this->gender) ? $this->gender->name : null;
}
```

Then you can do `$user->gender_name`

If you want this available in your response you can do in your model:

```
 protected $appends = ['gender_name'];
```